# Mysql query sum and Subtraction sum tabels

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, sql-order-by, subtraction

I need to this query

Table **Base**:

```
Id name
1  ex1
2  ex2
3  ex3
```

Table A

```
ExtId  p
1      10
1      20
2      40
3      10
3      10
```

Table B

```
ExtId  p
1      10
1      5
3      5
3      5
```

Table C

```
ExtId  p
1      10
2      10
2      20
3      40
```

Output:

Table A.p + Table B.p - Table C.p:

```
id   p
1    35
2    10
3   -10
```

Comment: sumo id they arent in table A or B or C

Comment: AND (Table A + Table B) - Table c AND all id is in Table base

Comment: hi i need to like search  where TblBase.name like 'exam' who write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select B1.id, coalesce(Q1.p,0) + coalesce(Q2.p,0) - coalesce(Q3.p,0) as p
from Base B1
left join 
    (
    select ExtId, sum(p) as p
    from TableA
    group by ExtID
    ) Q1
  on B1.id = Q1.ExtID
left join 
    (
    select ExtId, sum(p) as p
    from TableB
    group by ExtID
    ) Q2
  on B1.id = Q2.ExtID
left join 
    (
    select ExtId, sum(p) as p
    from TableC
    group by ExtID
    ) Q3
  on B1.id = Q3.ExtID
```

Comment: if like search by fild name in tbl base

Comment: where name like 'exam'

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping your id value sums and then calculate them:

```
SELECT
      A.id
    , A.P + B.p - C.p
FROM
    [Table Base] AS T
         INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
          ExtId
        , SUM(p) AS [p]
    FROM
        [Table A] AS A
    GROUP BY
        ExtId
    ) AS A
        ON T.id = A.ExtId
        INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
          ExtId
        , SUM(p) AS [p]
    FROM
        [Table B] AS B
    GROUP BY
        ExtId
    ) AS B
        ON T.id = B.ExtId
        INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
          ExtId
        , SUM(p) AS [p]
    FROM
        [Table C] AS C
    GROUP BY
        ExtId
    ) AS C
        ON T.id = C.ExtId
```

Comment: sume id they arent in table a  AND all id in Table Base

Answer (score 0):

My solution as below:-

```
CREATE TABLE Base (Id INT, name NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO Base VALUES (1, 'ex1'), (2, 'ex2'), (3, 'ex3')

CREATE TABLE TableA (ExtId INT, p INT)
CREATE TABLE TableB (ExtId INT, p INT)
CREATE TABLE TableC (ExtId INT, p INT)

INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1, 10), (1, 20), (2, 40), (3, 10), (3, 10)
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (1, 10), (1, 5), (3, 5), (3, 5)
INSERT INTO TableC VALUES (1, 10), (2, 10), (2, 20), (3, 40)

SELECT BS.Id, BS.name, ISNULL(A.A_total, 0) + ISNULL(B.B_total, 0) - ISNULL(C.C_total, 0)
FROM Base BS
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ExtId, SUM(p) AS A_total FROM TableA GROUP BY ExtId) A ON BS.Id = A.ExtId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ExtId, SUM(p) AS B_total FROM TableB GROUP BY ExtId) B ON BS.Id = B.ExtId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ExtId, SUM(p) AS C_total FROM TableC GROUP BY ExtId) C ON BS.Id = C.ExtId
ORDER BY BS.Id
```

Comment: hi i need to like search where TblBase.name like 'exam' who write this?

Comment: hi Doraemon top coomment